# how to save radio button state

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

am working on android application in which i open own custom dialog box and i use radio button in when i select radio button no doubt it selected and work but when i again open dialog box all radio button deselected i want to save the state of previous button

```
enter code here
 private void DiscountDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.burstinterval);
    dialog.setTitle("Timer");
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    final RadioButton no = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);

    final RadioButton first = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.first);

    final RadioButton second = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.second);

    final RadioButton third = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.third);

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.no).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t1);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("no", no.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "no_timer");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t2);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("first", first.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "2");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.second).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t5);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("second", second.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "5");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.third).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t10);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("third", third.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "10");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

after adding answer

```
enter code here



     private void DiscountDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.burstinterval);
    dialog.setTitle("Timer");
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    final RadioButton no = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);


    final RadioButton first = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.first);


    final RadioButton second = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.second);



   // third.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("third", false));
    final RadioButton third = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.third);


    dialog.findViewById(R.id.no).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t1);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("no", no.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "no_timer");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t2);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("first", first.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "2");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.second).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t5);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("second", second.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "5");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.third).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.setImageResource(R.drawable.t10);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("third", third.isChecked());
            edit.putString("my_preference_timer", "10");
            edit.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    no.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("no", false));
    first.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", false));
    second.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("second", false));
    third.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("third", false));

}
```

Comment: you can make it simple by using radioGroup when any radiobutton checked then store checked radiobutton id and when re populate show radio button checked respectively

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Save State of Radio Buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586837/android-save-state-of-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
no.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("no", false));
first.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", false));
second.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("second", false));
third.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("third", false));
```

after

```
dialog.show();
```

Comment: no.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("no", false));

Comment: @Rohit5k2 when i add  it show checked only third option but i want what i previous select that show

Comment: @HarpalSingh Also try those 5 lines of code I suggested after `dialog.show();`

Comment: @HarpalSingh May be because dialog is not visible by then is causing the issue. Add those 5 lines of code I suggested after `dialog.show();`

Comment: @HarpalSingh you are using `edit.putBoolean("no", third.isChecked());`. In every onClick method you have "no". it should have  "first", "second", "third" in respective click methods

Comment: @HarpalSingh probably copy paste error. Your original code had it right.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 functionality of my code is working but i only want when i open dialog box again it will show previous checked that i checked

Comment: I am just saying when you are saving the radio button status inside `onclick` method you are passing `"no"` everywhere. Its should be `"first"`, `"second"` and `"third"` in respective `onClick` methods. Read my last two comments

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Radio group** and check its Radiobutton by ID. 
Like this on Create

```
 prefs = getSharedPreferences("LANG_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.language);
    rg.check(prefs.getInt("lang_btn_id", R.id.amharic));
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

and on **onCheckedChanged** of radio group use something like this

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
    Log.w("SettingActivity", "Radio Changed");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LANG_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
        case R.id.urdu:
            editor.putInt("lang_code", 0);
            editor.putString("lang_name", "ar");
            Log.d("Checked","urdu");
            break;
        case R.id.eng:
            editor.putInt("lang_code", 1);
            editor.putString("lang_name", "en");
            Log.d("Checked", "english");
            break;
        case R.id.amharic:
            editor.putInt("lang_code", 2);
            editor.putString("lang_name", "am");
            Log.d("Checked", "amharic");
            break;
    }
    editor.putInt("lang_btn_id", radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    editor.commit();
```